# Collision not working in swift + sprite kit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

```
import SpriteKit



// fix spawning so close to the middle
// get ball col working
// set width apart/ height they must be apart (if statement)


let BallCategoryName = "ball"
let BarCategoryName = "block"
let BarNodeCategoryName = "blockNode"

let GreenBallCategory  : UInt32 = 0x1 << 0
let RedBallCategory: UInt32 = 0x1 << 1
let GreenBarCategory : UInt32 = 0x1 << 2
let RedBarCategory : UInt32 = 0x1 << 3

class GameScene: SKScene,  SKPhysicsContactDelegate {



    //VARIABLES IMPORTANTE//

    var greenBall = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "greenball")
    var redBall = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "redball")
    var bar0 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bar0")
    var bar1 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bar1")
    var bar2 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bar2")
    var bar3 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bar3")
    var bar4 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bar4")
    var bar5 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bar5")


    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

        physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self


     // BALL CHARACTERISTICS//


    //Green//

        greenBall.position  = CGPoint(x: frame.size.width*0.25,  y:  (frame.size.height * 0.95)/2)
        greenBall.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
        greenBall.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: greenBall.size.width/2)
        greenBall.physicsBody?.friction = 0
        greenBall.physicsBody?.restitution = 1
        greenBall.physicsBody?.linearDamping = 0
        greenBall.physicsBody?.angularDamping = 0
        greenBall.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        greenBall.name = BallCategoryName
        addChild(greenBall)

    //Red//

        redBall.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5 , y: 0.5)
        redBall.position  = CGPoint(x: frame.size.width*0.75 ,  y:  (frame.size.height * 0.95)/2)
        redBall.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: greenBall.size.width/2)
        redBall.physicsBody?.friction = 0
        redBall.physicsBody?.restitution = 1
        redBall.physicsBody?.linearDamping = 0
        redBall.physicsBody?.angularDamping = 0
        redBall.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        redBall.physicsBody?.dynamic = false



        addChild(redBall)



        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////


        // SETTING UP SCENE//

        GameScene(size: self.view!.frame.size) //WHy not work

        let borderBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: self.frame)
        self.physicsBody = borderBody
        self.physicsBody?.friction = 0




        // BACKGROUND COLOR




        // PHYSICS //

        physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0, 0)





        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////



        //  EXTRA BARS
        var midBar = SKShapeNode(rectOfSize: CGSize(width : frame.size.width, height: 3))
        var menuBar = SKShapeNode(rectOfSize: CGSize(width : frame.size.width, height: 3))
        var invisMenuBar = SKShapeNode(rectOfSize: CGSize(width: frame.size.width, height: 0.00001))
        var botBar = SKShapeNode(rectOfSize: CGSize(width : frame.size.width, height: 3))

        midBar.fillColor = SKColor.whiteColor()
        menuBar.fillColor = SKColor.whiteColor()
        invisMenuBar.fillColor = SKColor.purpleColor()
        botBar.fillColor = SKColor.whiteColor()

    ////MID BAR////
      var minus = frame.size.height * 0.049
        midBar.position = CGPoint(x: frame.size.width/2, y: (frame.size.height * 0.95)/2)
          addChild(midBar)



    ////BOT BAR////
           botBar.position = CGPoint(x: frame.size.width/2, y: 0 + (botBar.frame.size.height/2))
        addChild(botBar)


    ////MENU BAR////
            menuBar.position = CGPoint(x: frame.size.width/2, y: frame.size.height - (frame.size.height * 0.05))

         addChild(menuBar)

  //// INVIS MENU BAR ////
        invisMenuBar.position = CGPoint(x: frame.size.width/2, y: frame.size.height - (frame.size.height * 0.047))
        invisMenuBar.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: invisMenuBar.frame.size)
        invisMenuBar.physicsBody?.friction = 0
        invisMenuBar.physicsBody?.restitution = 1
        invisMenuBar.physicsBody?.linearDamping = 0
        invisMenuBar.physicsBody?.angularDamping = 0
        invisMenuBar.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        invisMenuBar.physicsBody?.dynamic = false


        invisMenuBar.zPosition = 100
        menuBar.zPosition = 5

        addChild(invisMenuBar)




   // TEST STUFF WITH BARS //

        let chosenOne = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bar4")
        chosenOne.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX - chosenOne.frame.width/2 - 50 ,  y: self.frame.height * 0.75)





        addChild(chosenOne)


        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////


        //// SETTING UP MY CONTACT ///

        greenBall.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = GreenBallCategory
        chosenOne.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = RedBarCategory

        greenBall.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = RedBarCategory
        chosenOne.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = GreenBallCategory

        chosenOne.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: chosenOne.frame.size)


        func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
            // 1. Create local variables for two physics bodies
            var firstBody: SKPhysicsBody
            var secondBody: SKPhysicsBody

            // 2. Assign the two physics bodies so that the one with the lower category is always stored in firstBody
            if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask {
                firstBody = contact.bodyA
                secondBody = contact.bodyB
            } else {
                firstBody = contact.bodyB
                secondBody = contact.bodyA
            }

            // 3. react to the contact between ball and bottom
            if firstBody.categoryBitMask == GreenBallCategory && secondBody.categoryBitMask == RedBarCategory {
                //TODO: Replace the log statement with display of Game Over Scene
                println("Hit bottom. First contact has been made.")
            }
        }
```

I'm following http://www.raywenderlich.com/84341/create-breakout-game-sprite-kit-swift to the letter. I've got the self contact delegate all set up, the two do hit each other but it doesn't print to the logs to prove the collision stuff is actually working.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is `didBeginContact` definitely being called?

Comment: Lol, forgive me here. Honestly just following this guide and ran into this issue. Sort of just learning as I go and super, super new to this.  So my answer is I'm not sure. How do I call it?

Comment: *You* shouldn't be calling it; if you've got your delegate setup properly it will be called for you when nodes collide. Try setting a breakpoint or using `println(...)` in `didBeginContact` to check it's being called.

Comment: I've got the SKPhysicsContactDelegate{ and the,  physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self, and the  "if the first body= greenballcat and second = rebarcat then println "it did it".

Comment: Can you post the code for the rest of your `SKScene`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `didBeginContact` method is inside the `didMoveToView` method. Since both methods in [`SKPhysicsContactDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsContactDelegate_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/SKPhysicsContactDelegate/didBeginContact:) are optional:

```
protocol SKPhysicsContactDelegate : NSObjectProtocol {
    optional func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact)
    optional func didEndContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact)
}
```

you're not being warned that `GameScene` doesn't implement the methods.

Move `didBeginContact` out of `didMoveToView` and you should be fine.

(On a side note: I would advise that you split up `didMoveToView` into several, smaller methods. It'll make it easier to understand what's going on because, at the moment, it looks pretty bloated.)

Comment: Thannkkk gooodness. I had no idea you couldn't do that!  Seems like there's so much "You don't know what you don't know" sorta stuff that can really stump you.

Thanks for taking the time with me, appreciate it.

Comment: My advice would be keep at the tutorials and experiment with what you can and can't do; you'll soon know out all those things that would previously have had you stumped. I'm glad that's working for you now though, good luck with your project!

Comment: Haha thanks for the words of encouragement and thanks again for the help! Have a good one mate.

Comment: Sounds like something for another question really.